# Is it posssible to define multiple replicas for different values of custom metrics in HorizontalPodAutoscaling

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

I am using HPA(HorizontalPodAutoscaling) along with custom metrics in kubernetes. I can scale my pod count according to my custom metrics value.

```
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2alpha1
metadata:
  name: sample-metrics-app-hpa
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    kind: Deployment
    name: sample-metrics-app
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: Object
    object:
      target:
        kind: Service
        name: sample-metrics-app
      metricName: http_requests
      targetValue: 100
```

Is it possible to  define multiple target value, for example if the http request hits 100 then the pod should scale by 10(min replica should be 2 for this), if it hits 1000, then the pod should scale by 20(min replica needs to be 10).

Answer (score 0):

As I know it is not possible to achieve such result with HPA. Moreover, your configuration says that every 100 http requests hpa will add 1 more pod. Not 2 --> 10 at once, but again, 1-->2-->3 every 100 requests.

For more details please reach  [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler Walkthrough](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/)

Comment: Yeah,Thank you @VKR, I made it possible via changing the metric types from "Object" to "Pods" and defined "averageValue" as 100.But I am confused how the scaling is happening in this configuration. I mean, at what basis the pod scaling is happening.